# Pivote Table from DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create something like a pivote table from a dataframe in R. 
I have the a dataframe with several columns and several rows. 
Let's say it has this structure(it has many columns, I dont know how many (is variable) and I can guess with other variable their name:

```
     DATE     1      7      15      30
2008-01-01   value  value  value  value
2008-01-02   value  value  value  value
```

I need an output with this structure:

```
   DATE      TENOR    VALUE  
2008-01-01   1        value  
2008-01-01   7        value 
2008-01-01   15       value 
2008-01-01   30       value 
2008-01-02   1        value  
2008-01-02   7        value 
2008-01-02   15       value 
2008-01-02   30       value
```

Did I explain myself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it, but I am stuck, as I am a beginner in R

Comment: I did search for an hour or so, but Im still stuck... Thanks for the link. I'll take a glance

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your help, anyway